# Align JComponents with different parents

Tags: java, swing, alignment, layout-manager, jcomponent

I building a quite complicated GUI using Swing, and have come across a alignment issue that I need help with. The code below is a simplified version of the situation I have, in order to make the problem clearer.

Basically I'm wondering it there is a possibility to align a JComponent with a JComponent that has a different parent component? I am aware that I could insert invisible Box components in order to solve this, but I don't think this is a good solution for several reasons.

In the code below, I want the Child to be the same size and vertically aligned with the Niece (basically have Child in the same position as Niece, just in a row below it). Underneath Sister should just be empty space.

Is there someway to get the left alignment of Niece relative to the main content pane, and set the left alignment of Child to be the same?

Code:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import java.awt.Container;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.awt.Dimension;

public class Test extends JFrame {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {

        JTabbedPane tabPane = new JTabbedPane();
        JTextField edPane1 = new JTextField("Sister");
        JTextField edPane2 = new JTextField("Child");
        JTextField tabEdPane = new JTextField("Niece");
        edPane1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 100));
        edPane2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 100));
        tabEdPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 100));
        tabPane.addTab("Tab", tabEdPane);

        Container contPane = getContentPane();

        GroupLayout layout = new GroupLayout(contPane);
        setLayout(layout);
        layout.setAutoCreateGaps(true);
        layout.setAutoCreateContainerGaps(true);

        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(edPane1)
                    .addComponent(tabPane))
                .addComponent(edPane2)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup()
                    .addComponent(edPane1)
                    .addComponent(tabPane))
                .addComponent(edPane2)
        );

        setTitle("Title");
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Any suggestions of a solution might be helpful!

EDIT: This is what it should look like:

[image: Intended look]

Comment: *"Basically I'm wondering it there is a possibility to align a JComponent with a JComponent that has a different parent component?"* Not really, except for special cases like a single column/row `GridLayout` pair where each is stretched to the same height/width.  Maybe this GUI needs a more  sophisticated layout like `GridBagLayout` or `GroupLayout`.

Comment: Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I am using GroupLayout. A drawing of the intended look has been added to the post.